# Building a path from points by distance

Tags: qgis, layers, points-to-line

I have layer of points of which I need to build lines. Standart Points to path function doesn't suit me.  I have data on time, but it does not reflect the order of connection that I need. I need to connect them by distance. That is, if the distance between two points is less than 10 meters - draw a line. Is it possible?

Comment: I didn't find any tool or I missed. But it can be done using python script. If you prefer python code, I can add as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind working with QGIS' natively supported *SQLite* dialect, this breaks down to a trivial self-`JOIN` on the distance threshold:

- either  create a [*Virtual Layer*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?highlight=virtual%20layer#creating-virtual-layers), or use the [*DB Manager*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_db_manager.html)
- run (assuming your point source layer is called `pts`, and has an `id` column)

  ```
  SELECT  a.id,
          b.id,
          MakeLine(a.geometry, b.geometry) AS geometry
  FROM    pts AS a
  JOIN    pts AS b
    ON    ST_Distance(a.geometry, b.geometry, 1) < 10
  WHERE   a.id <> b.id
  ;
  ```

The optional third parameter to `ST_Distance` (`use_ellipsoid BOOLEAN`), if given, will force the function to calculate distances based on a *sphere* (`use_ellipsoid=0`) or *spheroid* (`use_ellipsoid=1`), rather than on the Cartesian plane; this requires the geometries to be in a geographic reference, but works on *meter* as unit instead of the unit of the underlying CRS.

Note that this effectively aggregates attributes from two rows; the natively compiled *SQLite* version doesn't have any array support other than string concatenation. I simply added the `id` of both points to the output as reference; you could e.g. use the timestamp here.